# Some Css classes missing in dreamweaver css autocomplete

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CS6. When I type a class name it usually displays a list of all the classes available in the css stylesheets attached to the html document, but this time a few classes are there in my bootstrap 3 Css stylesheet but they do not appear in the DW's autocomplete. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that the classes you are using are available in the version of bootstrap that you are using?

Comment: Yes, the missing classes are .navbar-right and .navbar-left. I ccan see them in the code inspection tools of chrome. The class is working fine. But it just doesnt appear in the class name suggestions. I have experienced it for the first time

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the bootstrap css file, the .navbar-left & right classes are inside a media tag.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-left {
  float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
  float: right !important;
  }
}
```

It is not declared anywhere else, dreamweaver does not pick up classes within the @media tag. They would have to be declared outside first.